# Can you send a created order to square POS but without paying ahead?

Tags: square-connect

Love the order ahead use-case: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/orders-api/order-ahead-usecase

Trying to figure out though. It says: "The customer kicks off the process by ordering one small coffee and one chocolate chip cookie using your order-ahead app. The customer chooses to pay using the app and pick their order up at CoffeeCool’s location."

Can the customer therefore "choose" to pay at pick-up? I'd still want the created order to be sent to the POS, so that the kitchen can start preparing it and the customer is not waiting.

Essentially this would be like replicating the "Save" rather than "Charge" option if this order were being manually made at the Square POS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently only orders that have a charge associated to it will appear in the Square app and unfortunately the option to pay at time of pickup isn't currently available.

Comment: got it, is there any other way to use the API to create an order, but then have the customer actually pay on-site? because the % fee is different with in-app payment (card-not-present) vs swipe at POS (card present) so trying to figure out how to get the lower, card present rate, if the customer is ordering themselves

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can. You can set it up from the dashboard ( your computer) not directly from the POS. The issue is that it will prompt you to give a name to the order